# How to export an animation from Maya to three.js workflow

Tags: three.js, maya

I'm trying to understand how to export an animation from Maya to threejs to get the following effect:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse or
 http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending

I'm using the maya exporter here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya

But i'm not sure what the correct export options are and what kind of threejs code is needed for playback.

- morph targets? bones? keyframes?

  - How do you specify in the exporter?
- Are there any gotchas when exporting?

Heres a simple maya project for the animation below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz4h83ek6zckpll/maya-test.zip?dl=0

[image: example animation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buddy of mine helped out with the solution:

1. Select your model
2. Edit > Keys > Bake Simulation > []
3. Check the Control Points checkbox, then bake simulation
4. File > Export All > Three.js
5. Check Bake Animation in export settings

working here:

http://maya.surge.sh/